# Swift 2.2: Using GKRandomSource with an array of UIImages

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, uiimage

I am trying to randomize an array of UIImages by doing the following:

```
import UIKit
import GameplayKit

//Create an array of the pictures. They are already in xcassets.

var picturePieces = [UIImage(named: "concordTL"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordTC"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordTR"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordLC"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordC"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordRC"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordBL"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordBC"), 
                     UIImage(named: "concordBR")]

//Randomizer function using GKRandomSource


func shuffle() {
var shuffledPicturePieces = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(picturePieces)
```

**HERE: I keep getting the error "Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage?]' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'" at the (picturePieces).**

**Can GKRandomSource not work with UIImage?**

I then want to assign each of the randomized UIImages in shuffledPicturePieces to each of my @IBOutlets as shown below:

```
//Outlets for ImageViews.

@IBOutlet weak var EasyTopLeft: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyTopCenter: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyTopRight: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyLeftCenter: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyCenter: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyRightCenter: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyBottomLeft: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyBottomCenter: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var EasyBottomRight: UIImageView!

//Method to get a picture for the puzzle.

@IBAction func getPictureButton(sender: UIButton) {
    shuffle()

    if EasyTopLeft == nil{
        EasyTopLeft.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[0]]
        EasyTopCenter.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[1]]
        EasyTopRight.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[2]]
        EasyLeftCenter.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[3]]
        EasyCenter.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[4]]
        EasyRightCenter.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[5]]
        EasyBottomLeft.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[6]]
        EasyBottomCenter.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[7]]
        EasyBottomRight.image = shuffledPicturePieces[Int[8]]
    }


    else{
        NSLog("Image already loaded!")
    }



}
```

**HERE: I keep getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'shuffledPicturePieces'" for each item in the IF statement.**

Thank you for your help!

-Frank

Answer (score 0):

Your first error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage?]' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'

happens because you're passing an array of Optional type to a function that expects an array of non-optional type. Since you "know" those images are present in your asset catalog, an easy way to make them non-optional is to force unwrap them (note the added `!`):

```
var picturePieces = [UIImage(named: "concordTL")!, 
                     UIImage(named: "concordTC")!,
                     // ...
```

Alternatively, you could handle errors more explicitly with a functional programming style:

```
let imageNames = ["concordTL", "concordTC", /*...*/]
let picturePieces = imageNames.map { name in
    guard let image = UIImage(named: name) 
        else { fatalError("missing from asset catalog: \(name)") }
    return image
}
```

---

Note that once you have an array of images (`[UIImage]`), you can pass it to `GKRandomSource.arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray`, but the shuffled array loses element-type information — its type is `[AnyObject]`. To treat it as an array *of images* again you'll need a cast:

```
let shuffledPicturePieces = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom()
    .arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(picturePieces) as! [UIImage]
```

---

Your second issue:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'shuffledPicturePieces'

has to do with scope. You defined an array called `shuffledPicturePieces` *within* the `shuffle()` function, so that name is valid only elsewhere within that same function. Inside another function, like your `getPictureButton`, that name doesn't exist.

If you want `shuffledPicturePieces` to exist globally (or within an instance of your class), make it a property instead. For example:

```
class Whatever {
    let picturePieces = ["concordTL", /*...*/].map { /* as above */ }
    var shuffledPicturePieces: [UIImage]!
    func shuffle() {
        shuffledPicturePieces = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom()
            .arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(picturePieces) as! [UIImage]
        // notice no var or let here — assign to the instance property,
        // don't create a new local variable
    }
    func getPictureButton(sender: UIButton) {
        // as before
    }
}
```

---

By the way, it helps communication with others, debugging, and things like Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting if you use standard Swift naming conventions: Your `@IBOutlet` variables' names should start with a lower case letter (`easyTopLeft`, etc), so they don't get mistaken for types.